# Why doesnt this MySQL Statement work?

Tags: mysql, group-by

This SQL statement tells me i have an error near group by ...
it works fine for doing a select * from and no set. any ideas?

```
UPDATE  orders o
JOIN (select i.oid, i.pid    from  items i  where i.pid <> '4970'   ) i ON o.oid= i.oid
JOIN products p  ON i.pid = p.product_id 
SET o.sortloc =  concat('zzz',p.location)
where  (o.stat = '4' OR o.stat = '0' OR o.stat = '20'  )
group by o.oid
having  count(*)  > 1
```

Comment: `UPDATE tablename` not `UPDATE FROM tablename`

Comment: Not sure if `GROUP BY` makes sense in an update.

Comment: i need the group for the count * >

Comment: solved by removing group and moving count * to inner select

Comment: but still don't understand why  the select statement should be valid but not the update.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the count *  to the inner select.

```
UPDATE 
orders o
JOIN (select i.oid, i.pid, count(*) as ocnt    from  items i  where i.pid <> '4970' group by i.oid) i ON o.oid= i.oid
JOIN products p  ON i.pid = p.product_id 
SET o.sortloc =  concat('zzz',p.location)
where  (o.stat = '4' OR o.stat = '0' OR o.stat = '20'  )  and i.ocnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` != `SELECT`

If you look at the syntax for both statements: [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) and [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

You cannot `GROUP BY` results in `UPDATE`. When you select something and use `GROUP BY`, you are aggregating results. That is not the actual data and thus cannot be updated as is.